# If I want to play Low-Latency HLS streaming on safari native player, must #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION and #EXTINF be equal?

Tags: safari, http-live-streaming, low-latency

I make two low-latency hls streams to play on safari native player. The only difference is EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:

"First fine stream" with EXT-X-TARGETDURATION = EXTINF = 6sec;

"Second bad stream" with EXT-X-TARGETDURATION = 8sec, EXTINF = 6sec;

First stream plays fine on safari native player, while the second stream only download m3u8 and partial segments but cannot play at all.

I don't know what's the problem for the "second bad stream" which lead to the playing issue on safari native player, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

The following is sbr m3u8 content for the "second bad stream". (while #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6 is ok)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:9
#EXT-X-SERVER-CONTROL:CAN-BLOCK-RELOAD=YES,HOLD-BACK=24.000000,PART-HOLD-BACK=3.120000,CAN-SKIP-UNTIL=48.000000
#EXT-X-PART-INF:PART-TARGET=1.025000
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:280690554
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="test_3000_video-init.mp4"
#EXT-X-SKIP:SKIPPED-SEGMENTS=44
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690598.mp4
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690599.mp4
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-05-15T09:40:02.016Z
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690600.mp4
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690601.mp4
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part0.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part1.mp4"
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part2.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part3.mp4"
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part4.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690602.part5.mp4"
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690602.mp4
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part0.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part1.mp4"
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part2.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part3.mp4"
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part4.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690603.part5.mp4"
#EXTINF:6.000000,
test_3000_video-280690603.mp4
#EXT-X-PART:DURATION=1.000000,URI="test_3000_video-280690604.part0.mp4",INDEPENDENT=YES
#EXT-X-PRELOAD-HINT:TYPE=PART,URI="test_3000_video-280690604.part1.mp4"
#EXT-X-RENDITION-REPORT:URI="../test_1640_video/test_1640_fmp4Video.m3u8",LAST-MSN=280690604,LAST-PART=0
#EXT-X-RENDITION-REPORT:URI="../test_1100_video/test_1100_fmp4Video.m3u8",LAST-MSN=280690604,LAST-PART=0
```

From the Spec [HLS draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-08#section-4.4.3.1), it says: *"The EXT-X-TARGETDURATION tag specifies the maximum Media Segment
duration."* It seems that the "second bad stream" is also meet the requirements of HLS.

I tried to verify the stream by streamvalidator tool, but it only report the peak bitrate error, which is also exists in the "first fine stream".

I tried normal hls streams(non low-latency hls) on safari native player, the streams play fine. It seems that normal stream does't care about if "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION" is equal with "#EXTINF"

Comment: The problem may be related to your CAN-SKIP-UNTIL, try without skipping segments or change its value according to the specification.

CAN-SKIP-UNTIL - Its value is the Skip Boundary, a decimal-floating-point number of seconds. The Skip Boundary MUST be at least six times the Target Duration.
The Playlist Delta Update is a version of the Playlist in which Media Segments that are further from the end of the last (Parent) Media Segment in the Playlist than the Skip Boundary, as well as their associated tags, are replaced by an EXT-X-SKIP tag.

Comment: @mgukov, thanks a lot. I've made some attempts according to your suggestions, and I found the root cause.
For the "second bad stream":
CAN-SKIP-UNTIL is set as 6*TARGETDURATION(6*8sec), but the total duration(6*6sec) of segments list in M3U8 is less than 6*TARGETDURATION. After I add two more segments to M3U8 make total duration >= 6*TARGETDURATION, it works now.

Comment: Hi @stackxyz, I am also testing an HLS Low latency stream on Safari. I see that you got it to work. I observed that on Safari and AVPlayer low latency mode is used only if origin supports CAN-BLOCK-RELOAD=YES . Although this is optional as per HLS-LL spec. but Safari and AVPlayer seems to need this to get into LL mode. Did you experience this in your tests? Will appreciate any insights into it.